# Identical values on the x-axis of charts

Tags: swift, graph, charts, axis-labels, ios-charts

I am using the Charts to plot graph.Getting correct value at initially ,but when start to zoom graph, some values on the X-axis becomes identical.

have written the code like this.

```
   self.lineChartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 2, maxXRange: Double(dataPoints.count))
   self.lineChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
   self.lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
```

also the image of before zoom and after is attached.

[image: .This is the image before zoom]

[image: This is the image after zoom,some value become identical.]

Comment: You mean that the formatter you used is the same? Like you'd want to see also "Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4" for each year, instead of only the year? Do you have these different 4 values into you X Values Array?

Comment: As I shown in the second image,I want the year should not  repeated on zooming.Every year on the x-axis should come one time only.@Larme

Comment: Might be you have granularityEnabled = false somewhere else i guess.

Comment: you can pass chartView.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(someValue)